# Replace null value from the String with the " " value

Tags: java

I have a `string` which contains `null value` with some `string` value.I want to `replace` that null value with the`" "(blank)` value.
For example I have a string value

**Cap mbsonsl null** I want result like **Cap mbsonsl**(replace null).

So can anyone please suggest me what to do?

Comment: That is nice. Have you tried anything? Can we see your code? `String.replace` may be very helpful here.

Comment: Actually I have concat two values at the time of selection.sometimes I will get Cap metacin 20(example).So 20 is correct but if there is null in place of 20 then replace it with " ".

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = "Cap mbsonsl null";
s = s.replaceAll("null", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: In there before me! +1

Comment: s.replace is enough, instead of s.replaceAll

Answer (score 2):

`String.replaceAll` might be what you want.

**Example**

```
String test = "Cap mbsonsl null";

String noNull = test.replaceAll("null", "");

System.out.println(noNull);

// Outputs Cap mbsons1
```

And you should always make sure there is a *point* to running your code..

```
if(test.contains("null")) {
    // Replace the values.
}
```

**Extra Reading**

- Read the Java [String Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). It will tell you about all the awesome stuff `String` can do.

Answer (score 1):

this code remove only null word .
not remove word which is containing null word.
see example :

```
String withNull = "remove only null not having null contains value like annulling";
String withoutNull = withNull.replaceAll("\\s*\\bnull\\b\\s*", " ");
System.out.println(withoutNull);
```

Outpu is :

```
remove only not having contains value like annulling
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = " Cap mbsonsl null ";
s = s.replaceAll("null", "");
```